# Reading Bios With C#

Tags: c#

i am looking for reading of bios with c#,VS-2005 with full features and contents is there any best tutorial for that.

Comment: BIOS like Basic Input/Output System or like Biography or like something else? In any case what exactly would you like to read?

Comment: @Darin, I am interesting in study of how to reading device specifically HDD with C#,VS-2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some information available via Google for this.  It appears that [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/cc302051(en-us).aspx) is a good starting point.

Comment: WMI is by far the easiest general purpose way to do this and many other things.